# ¿Subir Api Adonisjs a AWS?

Tags: api, aws, adonisjs

Hola quiero subir una Api hecha en adonisjs a aws pero no me funciona, esto fue lo que hice, cree una instancia normal con el S.O Ubuntu y realice un git clone, después ejecute un

```
npm install --save
```

en la api que acababa de clonar para instalar los módulos y crear el archivo .env para asignar la configuración donde se iniciara el servidor, esta es la configuración predeterminada de un .env

```
HOST=127.0.0.1
PORT=3333
NODE_ENV=development
APP_NAME=AdonisJs
APP_URL=http://${HOST}:${PORT}
CACHE_VIEWS=false
APP_KEY=0fL3Ju674VAreZZkNYPe0gtUJcRRUUiX
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_USER=root
DB_PASSWORD=
DB_DATABASE=adonis
HASH_DRIVER=bcrypt
```

Se iniciar el servidor y todo bien, pero se iniciar en local , por la configuración del .env asi que modifico esto para que inicie en el puerto 3333 y ya, pero no me funciono.

Esta en la configuración para iniciar en el puerto 3333

```
HOST=
PORT=3333
NODE_ENV=development
APP_NAME=AdonisJs
APP_URL=:${PORT}
```

Al iniciar el servidor obtengo esto en la terminal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en el navegador web esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías describir mejor el error que obtienes?

Comment: Si claro, ya actualice la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por defecto, las instancias EC2 vienen con todos los puertos capados, salvo SSH. Tienes que editar el Grupo de Seguridad (*Security Group*), para que la instancia pueda ser accedida desde Internet o únicamente desde tu Intranet.

Comment: Si gracias, ya tenia asignado un grupo de seguridad para la instancia y si tengo acceso a esta, solo que al inciar la api en el puerto 3333 y acceder a la url no me deja, ejemplo 192.144.21.1:3333

Comment: @Satisfacción si, pero ese SG tiene que tener abierto el puerto 3333 para tcp o udp

Comment: Cierto, si me funciono graciasss.